# Simple Random Walk on Integers

Tags: random-walk

Question concerning a simple random walk on 1D.

Why the probability of hitting $\pm 2^n$ before return to $0$ is $2^{-n}$? I have no idea how to start...

Thank's!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like this; On your first step you go onto 1 (say).
Now the probability you hit 2 before 0 is a half (you either go left or right on your next step). Now we want to know whether we hit 4 next or 0, and we are in the middle of both, so again equal likelihood and the probability is 1/2. So both steps is a half squared and we get a quarter. This logic extended gives the answer you require...

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, suppose that the first step is to $1$ (rather than $-1$). Now you have a fair random walk with a walker at position $1$, and you're interested in the probability that it hits $N = 2^n$ before it hits $0$. You must have learnt a formula for this in class.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the formula. I'm a self-learner, so I didn't get such a formula :)

Comment: Well, if you're at position $a>0$ then the probability that you hit $0$ before you hit $b>a$ is $a/b$. See if you can prove this. This result shows that your problem is true for arbitrary integers replacing $2^n$.

Comment: Do you mean, hit $b>a$ before 0?

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. The probability that you hit $b$ before $0$ is $a/b$.

Comment: Thank's a lot. I got it starting from recurrence relation...